# wp category list based on author at author.php page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show category list on author.php page. Actually I made this file by get_categories() But it show all categories on this page. Code preview

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="page">
    <div class="article">
        <div id="content_box">                           
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                Title, excerp etc
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>                              
        </div>
    </div>      
    <!-- My Problem start here -->
        <div class="active-in widget">
            <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e('Active In', 'codersaiful'); ?></h3>
            <div class="post-info">
            <?php global $wp_query;
            $cats = get_categories();
                  $postAuthor = $wp_query->post->post_author;
                      $catlist = "";
                    foreach ( $cats as $c ) {
                        $catlist .= '<a href="'.esc_url( get_category_link( $c->term_id ) ).'" ><span class="thecategory">'.esc_html( $c->name ).'</span></a>';
                    }
                    ?>
            <?php echo $catlist; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
    <!-- My Problem end here -->    
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How I can get category only based on the author.
I am looking forward to hearing response from expert.
Thanks

Comment: If you are wanting to display categories applied to articles which single Author has written, it might be easier to go the other way and query the posts then pick out the categories into a separate array.  Either either way, that's going to be a hefty query.  Give this plugin a look: https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-all-posts-by-authors-nested-categories-and-titles/

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question asked on the WP SO site. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/813/list-categories-for-author-list-categories-function-inside-list-authors-functio

Comment: Thanks for comment. Hope: these comments will helpful.